# Use Fluent Emoji inside Ubuntu

Tags: 21.10, emoji

I am using `21.10`. I have `Segoe UI Emoji.ttf` in the `.fonts` folder ( I got it from Windows 11). I chose `SegoeEmoji` inside Inkscape and GIMP, without luck. But `Libre Office Impress` shows Fluent emoji without choosing anything. Is there any method to use Fluent emoji everywhere inside Ubuntu ? Thanks.

Comment: I expect a properly installed font to be available in Inkscape and Gimp as well. Perhaps it will work after updating your font cache: `fc-cache -r -v`

Comment: @vanadium tried , no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Windows uses a fundamentally different emoji font format than Linux; Microsoft’s format adds colour layers to a black and white base font, while the Linux format simply puts PNG images in a font file.

It only works in LibreOffice because it keeps its support for the Microsoft format in the Linux version.

The Fluent Emoji font is now open source, so you could make a Linux version of it, but no-one has done this yet.